# How would I turn one image into an entire set of buttons?

Tags: .net, vb.net, image, button

In my case I have a map of the office I'm in now, I'd like to make it to where when I click on each different room the appropriate event (routine, etc.) happens. I imagine it's possible but I've only ever seen (here and elsewhere) turning an image into a button, or using a button with an image as the background. But never have I seen of turning areas of a single image into multiple click-able objects. I know HTML had a thing where you tag specific pixel ranges using (x, y) start and (x, y) end to make a smaller portion of the image work as a button but I can't remember anything like that for visual basic or .Net.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "Visual Basic 2010 - " and such. That's what tags are for.

Comment: Native is the plan, also sorry John I'll do better next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look on this [article on this site: How to realize with WinForms in C# something like an image with map areas in a homepage (at hoovering cover areas with semi transparent rectangle)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865847/how-to-realize-with-winforms-in-c-sharp-something-like-an-image-with-map-areas-i)

and also this: [VBNet Image Map](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=626238)

Some Code snippet:

```
Public Sub New()

    Dim pts As New List(Of PointF)()

    pts.Add(New PointF(70, 160))
    pts.Add(New PointF(215, 244))
    pts.Add(New PointF(242, 217))
    pts.Add(New PointF(159, 71))
    pts.Add(New PointF(70, 160))

    Me.formulas.Add(New Formula(New PolygonF(pts.ToArray()), "P=RI^2"))

    '//create next polygon
    pts = New List(Of PointF)()
    pts.Add(New PointF(X, Y))
    pts.Add(New PointF(X2, Y2))
    '//etc...
    pts.Add(New PointF(X, Y))
    Me.formulas.Add(New Formula(New PolygonF(pts.ToArray()), _
                                             "Formula XYZ"))

    Me.InitializeComponent()

    Me.PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.OhmsLawWheel

End Sub
```

Comment: This really looks like exactly what I need. (I've already downloaded the example program from the forum.) Thanks a ton everyone. (can't up vote yet *shrugs*)

Answer (score 1):

The "thing where you tag specific pixel ranges" is called an Image Map and there is a .Net class for that.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagemap.aspx#Y0

The examples and related topic on the MSDN page can probably guide you.

This is for a web app, though. Is it ok with you?

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a web app check out [Image Maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map).  If you are creating a native app you may need to be more created.  If you have a vector based image you might be able to use it with WPF to create a simple interface.  If not you will either need to put buttons in each "room" or write your own code for bounds checking.